# problems with NSImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsimage

I'm having problems with the use of the class `NSImage`. I'm trying to use the function `initWithData:` but it does not work (anything related to `NSImage` doesn't work). Here is a simple example of what im trying. The `NSData` data is right.

My project is a commandline tool of foundation type.

```
NSData *imdata =[[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/JulianDavid/Desktop/ecoli_20000.png"];
if(!imdata){
    NSLog(@"there is data");
}
NSImage *imag=[[NSImage alloc]initWithData:imdata];
```

Comment: Is the file being loaded successfully?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)......... The Data is being loaded succesfully to NSData. but the data isnt being loaded to NSImage.

Comment: @Julian: Don't add crucial information in comments. Edit your question instead, and add the information there where people can see it when they first read your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImage"
```

means that the linker can't find the code implementing the `NSImage` class.  According to the [`NSImage` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nsimage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it's implemented in the AppKit framework.  So, in order for the linker to link the code properly, you need to link against the AppKit framework.  Do this by [adding the AppKit framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4) into your Xcode project.