# Integrating Settings inside the AppView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to implement InAppSettingKit and getting this error:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_MFMailComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in IASKAppSettingsWebViewController.o
  objc-class-ref in IASKAppSettingsViewController.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

InAppSettingKit is used for integrating settings inside the app.

The code I have imported had some **ARC** issues so I just disabled **ARC** for every file I had imported.But now I get this error.

I don't have any file named **MFMailComposeViewController** so how can I include it in **Compile Sources**?

I am new to iOS, so it would be appreciated if anyone can explain the steps to integrate setting inside the App.

Comment: You need to include the MessageUI framework into the target. ([See another answer for more on including frameworks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)) I posted this as an answer but it was converted to a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are new, you may not be familiar with how to add frameworks. Select the project in the project explorer, then select a target and then Build Phases. In Build phases, there is a section for "Link Binary with libraries". Select that option and click on + sign. It will show you a list of frameworks and you have to select and include "MessageUI.framework" from there.