# Label and NSTimer shadow design

Tags: ios, ios5, nstimer

I'm a beginner in iOS and need some leads to do something that don't feel that easy to do ...
I have to change my design for a timer (elapsed time and remaining time) that looks this way :
[image]

To something that look this way :

[image]

Would you have any leads to give to me (except for the shadow color and offset properties that I already know) ? My principal guess for now is : How differentiate these 2 states : gray when no time and blue when there is.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What part of changing it are you unsure about? How are you currently setting up the label (code or nib)?

Comment: No, juste trying to obtain this design : gray when no time and blue when there is. How differentiate these 2 states...

Comment: @Hetana Use two labels for the two different time components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're new to iOS development, so i'm not sure if it's a good idea to throw some 3rd party framworks at your head! but anyway, take a look at [TTTAttributetLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel). I'ts a drop-in replacement for UILabel and lets you style the parts of a UILabel text differently, so it could fit for your needs above!

Download the framework from the given link and look at the example project provided with it. And don't forget to include the CoreText framework into your project. (see "[How to add existing frameworks in Xcode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4))