# Apple Mach-O Linker Error (IAP)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase

I'm struggling with in-app purchases. Whenever I import StoreKit, I receive this error.
I've been at this for days with no luck.. Someone help?

Header File:

```
#import <StoreKit/StoreKit.h>    

#define kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification          @"kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification"

@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate>
{
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
}
@end
```

Implementation File:

```
#import "IAPManager.h"

@implementation InAppPurchaseManager 

- (void)requestProUpgradeProductData
{
    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet 
       setWithObject:@"com.runmonster.runmonsterfree.upgradetopro" ];
    productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
    productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [productsRequest start];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark SKProductsRequestDelegate methods

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    proUpgradeProduct = [products count] == 1 ? [[products firstObject] retain] : nil;
    if (proUpgradeProduct)
    {
        NSLog(@"Product title: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedTitle);
        NSLog(@"Product description: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.localizedDescription);
        NSLog(@"Product price: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.price);
        NSLog(@"Product id: %@" , proUpgradeProduct.productIdentifier);
    }

    for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
    {
        NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
    }


    [productsRequest release];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kInAppPurchaseManagerProductsFetchedNotification object:self userInfo:nil];
}
@end
```

The error thats killing me:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
      "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:
          objc-class-ref in IAPManager.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:    
Objc-class-ref in IAPManager.o    
Symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7    
Collect2: Id returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you have added the "Header", not the binary. Put the StoreKitFramework into the buildPhase->Link binary with libraries. Magically this will work ;)

Comment: Wow simple as that! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to add the **StoreKit.framework** to the libraries you link against.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4/3377682#3377682) shows how you can add it.