# Compiler Warnings with AFHTTPclient

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, afnetworking

I am a newbie to AFNetworking and running a simple application to understand how AFNetworking is working. I am following this tutorial on MobileTuts: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk_afnetworking/. I am able to get the app running with the information but I have these two warnings.

The two warnings are:

1. #warning "SystemConfiguration framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Network reachability functionality will not be available."

2.#warning "CoreServices framework not found in project, or not included in precompiled header. Automatic MIME type detection when uploading files in multipart requests will not be available."

I have already included the SystemConfiguration and CoreServices framework but these warnings still exist...

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In "YOURPROJECTNAME-Prefix.pch" file include this code

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

Comment: Add these frameworks to your project. Here is how you do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4

Comment: it's good to remember that order is important. If you import these after processing the AFHTTPclient.h, the warnings will remain

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am beginning to use swift in an obj-c project, and I had to add the two following headers to my `<project_name>-Bridging-Header.h` file:

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these Frameworks to your project. Here is how you do that

[How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Comment: And have you added the #import statements in your pch file ? You should do a Clean build of your project, and even quit Xcode. I always do that when I have unexplained issues