# "Include can't be found", how to fix it?

Tags: c++, xcode4.5, osx-mountain-lion, openscenegraph

I am developing using `OpenSceneGraph`. I installed it from a [**user-runnable installer**](http://www.artoolworks.com/dist/openscenegraph/3.1.x/).

When I try to compile an application using OpenSceneGraph, I have this error :

`Lexical or preprocessor error : Include cannot be found` for all `<osg/*>` includes like `<osg/AnimationPath>`.

The file is available here `/Library/Frameworks/osg.framework/Versions/92/Headers/XXXX` So following this solution on how to ["add existing frameworks" to the new Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4), I added **osg.framework** to the project.

[image]

any idea is a welcome.

I am using :

- IDE *Xcode 4.5*
- *Clang 4.1*
- *OS X Mountain Lion*

Comment: `find / -name missing_file_name`

Comment: @TadeuszKopec assuming OP is using linux

Comment: `find /  2>/dev/null -name missing_file_name` is always better @TadeuszKopec

Comment: As per some post I have found `Additional "include paths" can be specified in the Search Paths section` so I suggest you add `/Library/Frameworks/osg.framework/Versions/92/Headers/` like that. I hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to add `/Library/Frameworks` to the ***"Frameworks search path"*** in the *project settings*.

Answer (score 1):

When compiling you will have to add the include files using the `-I` option of the compiler and also possibly add library directory using the `-L` option of the compiler(the options may be a bit different if you are using compiler different from gcc).

I guess both library and the include directories for this product should be subdirectories of the install destination you have chosen. For the include directory of course look for directories containing some kind of header files `.h` or `.hpp` and for the libraries look for `.lib` or `.dll` doesn't the library documentation mention what includes and libraries you need and where you can find them?

EDIT: you will also have to tell xcode where to search for your includes. I tried googling it and [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=756243) is one of many results on how to add a directory to the include path of a project.

You will have to located which directory to add to the include path. It seems they set some [environment variables](http://openscenegraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenSceneGraph/doc/install.html#Mac%20OSX) in the official documentation for that.

Hope this helps.

Comment: which compiler are you using?

Comment: clang 4.1 but I am not yet compiling still configuring to use OpenSceneGraph

Comment: I added **osg framework** to the xcode project but nothing happened.

Comment: I think you need to make use of `OSG_FILE_PATH` as I understand it. Could you explore this directory and try to figure out which should be the directory you need to add to your include path?

Comment: I updated my question , the file is part of **osg.framework** I included the framework but still ... :(

Comment: About `OSG_FILE_PATH` this variable is supposed to point to `Data` and images provided by the developers team of OpenSceneGraph.