# adding movie to ipad app

Tags: objective-c, ipad

I am following a previous question on this topic trying to get a video to play inside my app. I have copied the video called iobserve1.mov into the resources folder and in my h file I import MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h. I am getting the following errors:

Apple Mach-O Linker Error 
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MPMoviePlayerController", referenced from:

and

Apple Mach-O Linker Error 
 linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
@interface ObViewControllerIObserveMovie ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *movieView; // this should point to a view where the movie will play
@end

@implementation ObViewControllerIObserveMovie

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iobserve1" ofType:@"mov"];
MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath]];
player.view.frame = CGRectMake(184, 200, 400, 300);
[self.view addSubview:player.view];
[player play];
}
```

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Comment: The Mediaplayer framework is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the MediaPlayer framework to your project? It contains the MPMediaPlayerController classes

Comment: Search for "adding frameworks in xcode" on google or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4

Comment: Got you. Great stuff thanks. While it now appears to work and load nothing actually plays. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry that's a completely different question you will have to ask.