# Xcode Audiocomponent Symbols not found and somehow cant use methods

Tags: xcode, audio, core-audio

im new to coding in c++, I only programmed in php and Java but I want to learn something more.
It may be not the best to start with Audio things but I already know how programming works.

But, I thought to test, get a bit of code from the Apple website and look what happens.
I pasted the beginning of the Code in my Project and got errors. And I dont really know what they mean and searching didnt give me any results.

Thats the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CoreAudio/CoreAudio.h>
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#include <AudioUnit/AudioUnit.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
  // insert code here...
  AudioComponent comp;
  AudioComponentDescription desc;
  AudioComponentInstance auHAL;
  //There are several different types of Audio Units.
  //Some audio units serve as Outputs, Mixers, or DSP
  //units. See AUComponent.h for listing
  desc.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Output;
  //Every Component has a subType, which will give a clearer picture
  //of what this components function will be.
  desc.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_HALOutput;
  //all Audio Units in AUComponent.h must use
  //"kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple" as the Manufacturer
  desc.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;
  desc.componentFlags = 0;
  desc.componentFlagsMask = 0;
  //Finds a component that meets the desc spec's
  comp = AudioComponentFindNext(NULL, & desc);
  if (comp == NULL) exit(-1);
  //gains access to the services provided by the component
  AudioComponentInstanceNew(comp, & auHAL);
  return 0;
}
```

and those are the errors i get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_AudioComponentFindNext", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
"_AudioComponentInstanceNew", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to add the `AudioUnit`, `CoreAudio` and `AudioToolbox` frameworks to your project. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377682/704596) for help on how to do that.

You are definitely jumping in the deep end if this is your first experience with C++. Good luck!