# Compilation error with _kCTSuperscriptAttributeName

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have been using `_kCTSuperscriptAttributeName` in my IOS project for super/subscript the text. The problem is when i compile the code, I get an error and it says

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:'_kCTSuperscriptAttributeName', referenced from:
```

I have imported both `CoreText/CTStringAttributes.h` and `CoreText/CoreText.h`.

What should i do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you haven't linked the CoreText framework.
You can do it in the Build Phases section of your target settings, as explained here: [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)