# i get error while running iAd Banner application...?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xml, xcode

```
 ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/macmini/Desktop/Test/iAd.framework/iAd, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/macmini/Desktop/Test/iAd.framework/iAd (2 slices)

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

  "_ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are adding iAd framwork

Comment: Brorther i am very sure..i have added iAd Framework...but not getting Banner View?

Comment: Why do you use your own iAd Framework?

Comment: I have used the framework following way....

Comment: In the project navigator, select your project
    Select your target
    Select the 'Build Phases' tab
    Open 'Link Binaries With Libraries' expander
    Click the '+' button
    Select your framework
    (optional) Drag and drop the added framework to the  Frameworks' group

Answer (score 0):

Although details are very few, Did you add iAd.Framework in you app? and also don't forget to import these two in your VC.

```
#import "iAd/ADBannerView.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
```

Comment: Brother already i have added this both frameworks..but still am getting same problem....I am using xcode 4.6.1 and simulator is 6.1...plz help me....

Comment: The deprecations have already been flagged by Xcode (see OP's screenshot) and missing include files will cause compilation failures, not link failures (again, see the OP's screenshot).

Comment: Brother i not am getting your point..can you explain me briefly?

Comment: @trojanfoe Edited, I did not mean that deprecation is the cause of the error. I said just as informative way. Thanks BTW.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't use the built-in iAd framework. If I interpret the path of the missing architecture warning correctly the iAd Framework your project uses is inside your project directory.

The framework should not be there. Remove this framework and add the system framework by following the instructions of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3377682/457406)

Comment: Brother i used the way which you said...But its not working..this is very small error,can't find it...

Comment: as long as `/Users/macmini/Desktop/Test/iAd.framework/iAd` appears in your warnings you have not done what I said.