# Library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, openssl, pjsip

I downloaded pjsip source code from online.It is running without any error.But, I integrated openssl lib and include file into that pjsip > ipjsua xcode project.After compiled xcode project, am getting library not found error and warning like below,

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/aahlaad/Desktop/swyxpjsip/iospj2/pjproject-2.2.1/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/../../../../pjlib/lib"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/aahlaad/Desktop/swyxpjsip/iospj2/pjproject-2.2.1/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/../../../../pjlib-util/lib"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/aahlaad/Desktop/swyxpjsip/iospj2/pjproject-2.2.1/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/../../../../pjmedia/lib"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/aahlaad/Desktop/swyxpjsip/iospj2/pjproject-2.2.1/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/../../../../pjnath/lib"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/aahlaad/Desktop/swyxpjsip/iospj2/pjproject-2.2.1/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/../../../../pjsip/lib"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/aahlaad/Desktop/swyxpjsip/iospj2/pjproject-2.2.1/pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/../../../../third_party/lib"'
ld: library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: @jww No dupe. Ah this is duplicated no dupe :) Again, static libraries are different with frameworks, and needs an extra procedure. Also, library search path issue is mostly unrelated to frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your derived Data and
Go to **Project->Build Settings->Search Paths**
and remove everything from **Framework/Header/Library Search Path** respectively and add your frameworks again in **Project -> General ->Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

Answer (score 0):

> ld: library not found for -lpj-arm-apple-darwin9

Here's how to add headers and libraries under Xcode. Its shows how to add OpenSSL, but in your case, do the same for PJSIP.

Headers:

[image]

Libraries:

[image]

***If*** your PJSIP library has *both* static archives and shared objects, then delete the shared objects. Even though iOS only allows static linking, Xcode will still link against a shared object if available. Apparently, the Xcode developers did not get the memo.

---

If you need help adding the PJSIP library to Xcode so it shows up under Frameworks and Libraries, then see [How to “add existing frameworks” in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4).

---

If you get the PJSIP library added but are missing architectures, you can use the following to see what's in the fat library:

```
$ xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info /usr/local/ssl/ios/lib/libcrypto.a 
Architectures in the fat file: libcrypto.a are: armv7 armv7s arm64 i386
```

Ideally, you will have the four architectures: ARMv7, ARMv7s, ARM64 and i386. i386 is for debug builds under the simulator.

If you are missing an architecture, then you should re-build the library with the missing architecture, and then use `lipo` to combine the different architectures into a single fat library.