# How to connect postgres to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, postgresql, mobile

I'm making an application on xcode 8.3.3 and am using swift to make the app. We have a hosted postgres database which is up and running but I don't know how to connect to it through swift and xcode. I have a host, port number, username and password but I don't know how to connect to the database so I can get the data. I'm a newbie to xcode, swift and basically programming in general please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple google search would yield tremondous results.

http://druware.tumblr.com/post/112163075395/getting-started-with-pgsqlkit-and-swift

I believe the above link should get you sorted.

Basically you have to use the C API libpq library.

See also:  https://github.com/stepanhruda/PostgreSQL-Swift

Comment: Hey, thanks but how do import the code from [link] (http://www.druware.com/pgsqltouch/)  as a .framework file?

Comment: @vsarunhah see: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010155-CH17-SW1 and also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4?rq=1

Comment: Sorry but there's another problem. The apple link isn't opening and the stackoverflow link helps but the problem is that the code isn't downloadable as a framework nor is it possible to copy it into a cocoa touch framework because it requires you to import "GenDBConnection" which currently doesn't exist. Can you help me with that? @David Farrugia