# how to import a framework into xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I downloaded the a frame work for parsing son links from [here](https://github.com/stig/json-framework)

and I googled how to to import a frame work into Xcode project, and it was as follows:

-highlighted the root of my project "the blue icon"

-chose 'build phases'

-chose 'link library'

-click on the plus sign '+'

-then, 'add another'

-navigated to the frame work I downloaded, but in the end nothing was added

please let me know how to import a frame work properly in Xcode

**img**:

**cocoaPod-1**

[image]

**cocoaPods-2**

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to "add existing frameworks" in Xcode 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

Comment: Why don't you use CocoaPods? That framework has the instructions in the readme.

Comment: Didn't check more carefully, but I didn't saw a .framework there. But did you check that https://github.com/stig/json-framework#installation ? CocoaPods is quite good, (Google iOS API recommends it).

Comment: @Larme in the link you provided it say:pod 'SBJson5', '~> 5.0.0'    where should I write this command please

Comment: Read about CocoaPods: https://cocoapods.org

Answer (score -1):

You can add it through Cocoapods. Follow below steps to do it properly.

Step1: **First open your terminal and type cd your project path.**

*Example:* ***UNTITLED:~ apple$ cd /Volumes/DATAPART/MyProjects/SampleProject***

Step2: **Create a pod file with pod init command.**

Example: 
***UNTITLED:SampleProject apple$ pod init***

Step3: **Open pod file and add your pod reference by copying this line into that file.**

***pod 'SBJson5', '~> 5.0.0'***

Step5: **Save and close your pod file.**

Step6: **Type *install pod* in terminal.**

Example: 
***UNTITLED:SampleProject apple$ pod install***

Step5: **Then A Xcodeworkspace file will be created in your project folder. Just close your Xcode and open your Xcodeworkspace file.** Thats it.

Comment: i am new to Apple OS,. my projects are under Macintosh/iOS-WorkSpace....how to navigate to my project folder using cmd

Comment: hold alt key and right click on your project folder, then click on copyPathName.. option. After that open terminal and enter cd then  simply past(cmd+v) and enter.

Comment: I hold alt key and r-click in the same time but no menus appear

Comment: Fist select your folder then do this steps

Comment: Option looks like : Copy "Your folder name" as Pathname

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use [CocoaPods](https://guides.cocoapods.org). From other comments by yourself, it seems you are not super confident in using Terminal so you can instead make use of the [CocoaPods App](https://cocoapods.org/app)

1. Download and install the [CocoaPods App](https://cocoapods.org/app)
2. Open the CocoaPods App and click `File > New Podfile from Xcode Project`
3. A window should open up and you can browse to your Xcode project file
4. A new window will open up with your Podfile and there will be a comment `# Pods for [project]`. Here is where you enter `pod 'SBJson5', '~> 5.0.0'`
5. At the top of the Podfile window, click `Install`
6. A `xcworskapce` will have been created for you. From now on, open that instead of the Xcode project file.

These are some rough/basic steps but you should read up more on CocoaPods to make sure you understand what is going on.

Some screenshots for reference:

[image: Add the pod to the Podfile]
[image: Successful installation of pod]
[image: Confirm pod installed]

Comment: please see the two pictures I added above 'cocoaPods-1' and 'cocoaPods-2' in either of them I can not write the command 'pod 'SBJson5', '~> 5.0.0''

Comment: What you you mean you can't write the command? You should be able to type it on the line under where it says `# Pods for Delegate-2`. I've added some screenshots to my answer to show where I am typing it.

Comment: do you mean I should write that command in the 1st screen shot in my question which is titled 'cocoa pod-1"??

Comment: Yes. Type it on the line under where it says `# Pods for Delegate-2`