# Changes in local framework are not updated in my project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I'm actually using an internal framework in one of my projects. Now I need to modify some of the code of that framework, however, it looks like the changes are no recognised at all by the project that is using that framework.

After committing some changes in the framework, build it and re-import it in the project and debug them, I can see that lines that I added are not executed at all.

I know this because when I add a breakpoint in the framework in one of the new lines, these are never executed as if they didn't exist.

I've tried to remove the framework from my project and add it again by following the steps of these [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3352664/how-to-add-existing-frameworks-in-xcode-4)

I expected that my changes in my framework are recognized/syncronised in the project as they use to do.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, so it would be really helpful your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it's necessary to follow the next steps strictly delete to don't have the same problem as I was.

1. Launch the framework project.
2. Assign the build type to a generic iOS device. Be sure all the classes are assigned to the Target.
3. Press the play (build) button.
4. The framework will appear on your desktop.
5. In the project that is going to use that framework, be sure to remove all the references related to the previous framework version, then delete it from the folder too.
6. Add the new framework version to its folder in the project.
7. Assign the references:

   - Drag the framework that has just been moved to the project, to the framework folder in Xcode.
   - Drag the framework, that has just been moved to the project, to Linked Frameworks and Libraries.

This worked for me, so maybe this is helpful for someone.