# Import private framework swift

Tags: swift, frameworks, private

I'm working on an app for macOS that need to use MediaRemote framework (private framework)
How can I import the MediaRemote framework to my project?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3352664/5133585) answer your question?

Comment: Nope, I tried everything nothing work

Comment: What did you try? And *how* did it not work?

Comment: Try to import MediaRemote framework and MediaRemote.h Xcode did not found the framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a MediaRemote.h and MediaRemote framework to your project
2. Add Objective-C bridge for your project
3. Add #import "MediaRemote.h" on the bridge file